# WPA Enterprise Wireless Bridge

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt

I live in college housing at a university with WIFI available. unfortunately, my bedroom(where I'd like to place my PC) gets little to no reception. I'd like to place a router in the strongest spot and rebroadcast.

I understand this can be done with DD-WRT/etc, but this particular network is WPA Enterprise with my own personal username/password.  I can't find any concrete evidence that I can get my router to act as a repeater for this encryption. I don't currently have a router to test it on, otherwise this would be easy, I just don't want to buy a router if it will be worthless to me.

Comment: FYI: Your university might have specific rules against this. Not saying it isn't possible, just might go against your housing rules and possible grounds for removal depending on their policy. Every school is different, so just make sure you know your limits.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to use two routers to work-around this problem, assuming you know your WPA Enterprise login credentials, or have access to them where they're stored on your PC.  (Or even a single access point with multiple radios, but the setup is probably more complex.)

You can use one router to connect to the WPA Enterprise network as a client.  See [this](http://blog.jozjan.net/2008/12/wrt54gl-as-8021x-client-aka.html)

Then use the second router to host a network that shares the first router's connection using NAT.