# Bridging Wireless connections and using access point

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, wireless-access-point

I am trying to setup a private wireless network in the form where my laptop is connected to Wi-Fi with internet access:

```
Wi-Fi (with internet) > Laptop > (Ethernet) > Wireless access point > other devices
```

to enable the other devices to connect to the internet through the laptop's Ethernet-connected access point.

The reason for this is that the original wireless network is WPA2-Enterprise encrypted and I have devices such as my Xbox and Apple TV that do not support this. (I can't simply change the wireless encryption as it is my university supplied Wi-Fi.)

Do I need to bridge the laptop's Wi-Fi and Ethernet connection ... or enable internet sharing?

Comment: Do they only provide wireless access (no ethernet ports) nowadays? Not to distract from your question but wouldn't it be more functional for you to set one wireless access point to act as a receiver (receiving the WPA2-Ent encryption) and plug a different wireless access point into one of its LAN ports and have the second one distribute the signal with your choice of encryption (assuming you don't mind buying another access point and that one of the two AP's can act as a repeater)?

Comment: This would be a great solution, if it is possible? I'll have a try if I can this would be a much preferable solution! Unfortunately I have no provided Ethernet ports

Comment: Fundamentally, it is possible. Specific hardware will make the difference. It may also be against your terms of use. You will need to make sure that the wireless bridge connecting to the WPA2-Ent network will support that type of authentication. Also, this will have to perform NAT. From there you can physically wire your devices or another wireless access point. Here are a couple posts I saw that ask basically your same question: http://www.avsforum.com/t/950439/please-help-me-connect-my-360-to-a-wpa2-enterprise-network http://superuser.com/questions/42822/wpa-enterprise-wireless-bridge

Answer (score 1):

For your proposed routing to work you need to enable Internet sharing.  A more elegant (but more expensive) solution might be to get another Access point type device which you can use as a AP Client (or something which can be made to do this with DD-Wrt or equivalent), and then take the ethernet out of that and into your AP.